# I installed java 7 on CentOS but it says I have version 1.4.2 installed?

Tags: installation, java, centos

What's the deal? I ran the RPM for java 7 64-bit and watched the folders populate at /usr/java but I can't run craftbukkit and when I do java -version it says 1.4.2?

Comment: I think, you have to set JAVA_HOME and PATH.

Comment: found the answer http://www.rndblog.com/how-to-switch-java-in-centos/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this command to change the default java:

```
/usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```

add a new one to the list:

```
/usr/sbin/alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_15/bin/java 2
```

Then run the top thing again to choose the '2' as default (or whatever number you put at the end of the install command above).

Comment: Works for Redhat too.